# WinAPI confusing function parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, parameters

The API reference for the function in question: [RmStartSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373668(v=vs.85).aspx).

The code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <RestartManager.h>

/*
DWORD WINAPI
RmStartSession(
    _Out_ DWORD *pSessionHandle,
    _Reserved_ DWORD dwSessionFlags,
    _Out_writes_(CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY + 1) WCHAR strSessionKey[]);
*/

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    WCHAR sessionKey[CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY + 1];

    // 1.
    DWORD *sessionOne = nullptr;
    auto returnCodeOne = RmStartSession(sessionOne, NULL, sessionKey); // = 160 ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS

    // 2.
    DWORD sessionTwo = 0xFFFFFFF;
    DWORD *pSessionHandleTwo = &sessionTwo;
    auto returnCodeTwo = RmStartSession(pSessionHandleTwo, NULL, sessionKey); // = 0 ERROR_SUCCESS

    // 3.
    DWORD sessionThree = 0xFFFFFFF;
    auto returnCodeThree = RmStartSession(&sessionThree, NULL, sessionKey); // = 0 ERROR_SUCCESS

    return 0;
}
```

Took me a while to realize why `1.` was giving me a `BAD_ARGUMENTS` error, since all of the variations above compiled fine and were legit language constructs.

The problem is that the function actually needs a pointer to a valid object and just uses that pointer to modify the object, does not modify the pointer itself. So if the pointer is `nullptr` then there's no object to modify, the function does not allocate an object itself.
*(Please correct me if my understanding above is wrong)*

That being said, why wasn't the function defined to request a reference to a `DWORD` to make it clear that it cannot be null, is there a specific reason to use a pointer here?
What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't this a C API? Where references do not exist?

Comment: Well that would explain everything, didn't think of it since all the documentation examples were in C++.

Comment: It is indeed a little weird that Microsoft has most of their low-level APIs as pure C, but seemingly refuse to acknowledge the existence of the language in their modern documentation.

Comment: The documentation for RmStartSession clearly states that the first parameter is an `out` value.  So why are you passing a null pointer?

Comment: There is no way a pointer to T can be modified and returned to the caller.  Try it yourself with your own code.  To modify a pointer, a pointer to the pointer would be passed.

Comment: Yeah figured it out as soon as I finished my reply :).

Comment: This is pretty much a non question. Stack Overflow is full of questions like this where nullptr is passed to a function that expects a valid pointer.

Comment: @David Heffernan I mildly disagree, the question is clumsily written, but the use of mutable reference instead of pointers for return value parameters when designing an API is a legit question in my mind.

Comment: @Frank there's no question in that comment of yours.

Comment: @Frank: *"Microsoft has most of their low-level APIs as pure C"* - The **entire** Windows API surface is exposed through C interfaces. There are a few concessions to C++ developers (like the GDI+ wrappers, or C++ interface declarations generated by the MIDL compiler). But those are simply higher-level abstractions over the C API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to this question:

1. This is a C api, so references were not available to the API writers.
2. There is a school of thoughts that using references for output value parameters is bad API design, and pointers should always be used, even if it means that passing a `nullptr` would be a disaster.

The idea is that reference-based output parameters are really confusing at the call site. Look at the following code:

```
void foo() {
   my_struct val;
   bar(val);
}

void foo_alt() {
   my_struct val;
   bar_alt(&val);
}
```

At first glance, one would not expect `bar` to modify `val` in the first example, but one would suspect it in the second.

Understanding what a function does by only looking at the call site is fundamental to self-documenting code, and mutable references often break that (unless it's really clear in the function name).